# 256-bit AES encryption for PDF on Mac OS X and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, macos, pdf

I have PDF files secured using 256-bit AES, requiring a password to open the file (Acrobat 9 or greater)

I can use Foxit Reader or Adobe Acrobat just fine on Windows, but I can't view those PDFs on Ubuntu or Mac OS X. What PDF readers for OS X and Ubuntu support 256-bit AES?

Here's a [sample file](http://left4churr.com/encrypted.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the sample file with [Adobe Reader for OS X](http://get.adobe.com/reader/otherversions/), and although you didn't provide a password, it did prompt for one, whereas Preview.app just displayed a blank page. (And it would make sense that Adobe Reader for OS X would provide the same functionality as Adobe Reader for Windows).

---

**Edit:** I just created a 256-bit AES encrypted test PDF with Acrobat Pro on Windows, tried to open it with Adobe Reader on OS X and it succeeded.

---

**Edit 2:** I just installed Adobe Reader 9.3.3 in my Xubuntu install and it could open the same AES-encrypted PDF. As for stock Ubuntu, there is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/poppler/+bug/472538) for Evince (the PDF renderer) to try and get AES support.

Comment: I'm sorry, the password is "password." Can you see if it works?

Comment: @Null Confirmed working on OS X and Linux `:)`

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), as of 2016-12-19, evince 3.18.2 can now open 128 bits AES encrypted PDF files.  However, it cannot handle strong encryption.  Following are related bug reports:

- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=726598
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1293282

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/606085)

Comment: In general, I agree with you Review Ramhound.  That said, the fact that I report the bug reports is of some value; the answer is that there are no open source solution and on some platform like ARM, Acrobat Reader does not exist.  Thus there is no solution.  The user would probably be interested to follow the open bug reports regarding this issue though.  I know I would.

Comment: "Sorry to post this as an answer; it should be a comment, but I do not have enough Karma to post a comment and it takes too long to get some." is a comment and does not answer the author's question.  It indicates you know what you submitted isn't an answer yet you despite knowing it was a comment submitted it as an answer.  This question isn't about ARM devices, so solutions not existing on those devices, isn't relevant

Comment: Ramhound, well, it seams that fixer1234 disagree with you.  And I believe I add value by putting forth this information.  Reputation does not come easy without polluting this site with stupid questions, so my only solution is to provide it as an answer.  Better provide the information now than wait 2 years for my reputation level go up to 50.

Comment: You will never gain reputation if you submit comments as an answer.  It's extremely easy to earn reputation.  Fixer did agree with me he just edited the answer which is what you should have done after you received the review comment.  Next time I won't be providing a comment if you submit a comment as an answer